# ggplot2 stacked bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize statistics of a bugtracking system.

What I would like to do is get an overview of incoming vs. fixed bug tickets and I think a barchart would be a good solution.

I've bought the book by Hadley Wickham 'ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis' and I'm trying to understand how geoms and stats works, but I think without additional support I will need much more time than I can spend on studying it.

It would be nice if you can help me getting an overview of in/out tickets based on the data table (Unfortunately attaching a csv seems not to be possible in questions).

```
id external    in.date      fixed in.cw fixed.cw
 1        x 01.11.2013 15.11.2013  1344     1346
 2          07.11.2013             1345     <NA>
 3        x 15.11.2013             1346     <NA>
 4          01.11.2013 15.11.2013  1344     1346
 5        x 07.11.2013 20.11.2014  1345     1447
 6          15.11.2013             1346     <NA>
 7        x 01.11.2013             1344     <NA>
 8          07.11.2013 05.01.2014  1345     1402
 9        x 15.11.2013 05.01.2014  1346     1402
10          01.11.2013 05.01.2014  1344     1402
11        x 07.11.2013             1345     <NA>
12          15.11.2013             1346     <NA>
13        x 01.11.2013 01.03.2014  1344     1409
14          07.11.2013 01.04.2014  1345     1414
15        x 15.11.2013             1346     <NA>
16          01.11.2013 01.05.2014  1344     1418
```

I think it would give a good overview if the fixed tickets are added in an additional layer to the plot.

Is it also possible to define a transparency value so overlayed bar plots will still be visible?

In the data I marked, there are also some entries as external tickets, which I would like to visualize somehow differently, to show the relation to the source of reporters by filling the count of external tickets with a pattern.

Later on I would also like to include the priority of the tickets but this would be one of the next steps besides adding a forcast, legend and maybe others.

This is what I did so far:

```
p <- ggplot(data=table) + stat_bin( aes(x=factor(in.cw), y=..count.., fill = factor(external)))  
p +  stat_bin(data=table, aes(x=factor(fixed.cw), y=..count..))#, fill = factor(external))
```

Which for the beginning is not bad I think :)

Could you show me how to get also the second layer containinig the fixed.cw tickets filled with colors and tell me how it is possible to define the line types for it?

Here a dump of the data used:

```
> dput(table)
structure(list(id = 1:16, external = c("x", "", "x", "", "x", 
"", "x", "", "x", "", "x", "", "x", "", "x", ""), in.date = c("01.11.2013", 
"07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", 
"01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", 
"15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013"
), fixed = c("15.11.2013", "", "", "15.11.2013", "20.11.2014", 
"", "", "05.01.2014", "05.01.2014", "05.01.2014", "", "", "01.03.2014", 
"01.04.2014", "", "01.05.2014"), in.cw = c("1344", "1345", "1346", 
"1344", "1345", "1346", "1344", "1345", "1346", "1344", "1345", 
"1346", "1344", "1345", "1346", "1344"), fixed.cw = c("1346", 
NA, NA, "1346", "1447", NA, NA, "1402", "1402", "1402", NA, NA, 
"1409", "1414", NA, "1418")), .Names = c("id", "external", "in.date", 
"fixed", "in.cw", "fixed.cw"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

This are just test data I created.

'external' markes entries created by the customer.

'in.date' defined the date of creation.

'fixed' defines the date of closing the error report.

'in.cw' and 'fixed.cw' is a representation of the year and callendar week of creation/closing the reports.

For the beginning I try to create one chart giving an overview about reports vs. closed reports. Ideally by separate externel from other entries.
Also a forecast based on the in.cw and fixed.cw values would be nice.
Regards
Wasili

Regards,
Wasili

Comment: First, call a dput() on your dataframe and paste the output for easy sharing. Second, you might want to explain what your columns are and what you are specifically trying to achieve--how many charts would you need to display the information, for example; what segmentation would be useful?

Comment: I don't know what type of frequency you have in the data, but you may want to summarize new cases by day, week month or something?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what sort of organization you are looking for, but this should get you started and assumes you want to summarize the data before plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

 test<-structure(list(id = 1:16, external = c("x", "", "x", "", "x", 
 "", "x", "", "x", "", "x", "", "x", "", "x", ""), in.date = c("01.11.2013", 
 "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", 
 "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", 
 "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013", "07.11.2013", "15.11.2013", "01.11.2013"
 ), fixed = c("15.11.2013", "", "", "15.11.2013", "20.11.2014", 
 "", "", "05.01.2014", "05.01.2014", "05.01.2014", "", "", "01.03.2014", 
 "01.04.2014", "", "01.05.2014"), in.cw = c("1344", "1345", "1346", 
 "1344", "1345", "1346", "1344", "1345", "1346", "1344", "1345", 
 "1346", "1344", "1345", "1346", "1344"), fixed.cw = c("1346", 
 NA, NA, "1346", "1447", NA, NA, "1402", "1402", "1402", NA, NA, 
 "1409", "1414", NA, "1418")), .Names = c("id", "external", "in.date", 
 "fixed", "in.cw", "fixed.cw"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

## code external/interlal variable
test$origin<-ifelse(test$external=='x','external','internal')

## store dates as actual date objects
test$in.date<-as.Date(test$in.date,format='%d.%m.%Y')
test$fixed<-as.Date(test$fixed,format='%d.%m.%Y')

## calculate process time in days for completed records
test$fixtime<-test$fixed-test$in.date

## discretize process time into groups for summary purposes
test$fixtime_categories<-cut(as.numeric(test$fixtime),breaks=c(seq(1,100,40),Inf))


## summarize data by categorized process time and whether origin=external
summary_data <- ddply(test,
                      .(fixtime_categories,origin), summarise, 
                      records = length(id)) 

## plotting
ggplot(summary_data)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x=fixtime_categories,y=records),stat="identity") +#,position="fill") +
  facet_wrap(~origin)+
  ggtitle('Process time by (exernal) filing status')
```

This yields the following chart, showing the count of cases by how long it took to complete them (here, the NA ones are those yet completed; those could be left out or included, depending on use case). The left panel is external cases only; the right panel internal ones.[image]